# Terminal Server not allowing users to log on

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

We use 4x Terminal Servers that allow users to log on correctly, but a newly added 5th TS is only allowing Admins to log on.

When trying to log on as a user who is not in the built-in 'Administrators' group the following error is displayed -

> To log on to this remote computer, you must be granted the Allow log on through Terminal Services right. By default, members of the Remote Desktop Users group have this right. If you are not a member of the Remote Desktop Users group or another group that has this right, or if the Remote Desktop User group does not have this right, you must be granted this right manually.

I have ensured that the follow is true -

1. The new server is in the same OU as the old servers, thus the same GPO's are applied.
2. All users that have been tested are a member of the `Remote Desktop Users` group.
3. The new server allows member of the `Remote Desktop Users` group to log on. I checked by following these steps -

   1. Rub `gpedit.msc`.
   2. Navigate to `Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment`.
   3. Ensure that the setting `Allow log on through Terminal Services` lists the `Remote Desktop Users` group.

What else can I check to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try enabling success and failure auditing for "logon events". That will probably only give you a second data point for the missing logon right, after the error message, but then you will know that the system really thinks the TS logon right is not there.

Comment: Have you checked the scope of the GPO's? GPO security settings? Item level targetting inside the GPO itself?

Answer (score 4):

Had same issue and I've found that my user was in `Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services` policy (in `Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment`). After I removed him from this policy I was able to log on successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your server is probably in Remote Administration mode, rather than Application Server mode. To change that, install the "Terminal server" component, either from Add/Remove Programs or from the "Configure Your Server Wizard".

Comment: Thanks, but I have already installed the Terminal Server role on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way:

1. Edited the GPO on the DC and added the problematic group to the policy "Allow log on through Remote Destop Services" (Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment).
2. Manually forced GPU update on the problematic computer with **gpupdate /force**
3. Manually added the group to the allowed "Remote User" on the problematic computer  in the section Advanced System Settings -> Remote -> Select Users... -> Add